# Apply a function to a rectangular subgrid with missing values

Tags: matrix, associations, missing

Some example data:

```
dt = <|"joe" -> <|"C1" -> 103, "C2" -> 104, "C3" -> 105, "C4" -> 107, "C5" -> 114|>,
  "tim" -> <|"C1" -> 101, "C2" -> 102, "C3" -> Missing[_], "C4" -> 101, "C5" -> 111|>,
  "ann" -> <|"C1" -> 102, "C2" -> 103, "C3" -> 103, "C4" -> 105, "C5" -> 114|>,
  "bob" -> <|"C1" -> 103, "C2" -> 103, "C3" -> 103, "C4" -> 104, "C5" -> 113|>|>
```

I want to apply a function to a rectangular subset of a matrix (given as an `Association` of `Association`s) by
specifying the `Keys`. Since I couldn't find a suitable inbuilt function I wrote:

```
MapAtKeys[dt_, fn_, {row_, col_}] :=
 Module[{pos, rp, cp},
  pos[d_, p_] := 
   Span @@ MinMax @ Flatten @ Values @ PositionIndex[Keys @ d][[p]];
  rp = pos[dt, row];
  cp = pos[dt[[1]], col];
  MapAt[fn, dt /. Missing[_] :> mis, {rp, cp}] /. mis :> Missing[_]
  ]
```

To skip missing values:

```
Plus[___, mis, ___] ^= mis;
Times[___, mis, ___] ^= mis;
Style[___, mis, ___] ^= mis;

MapAtKeys[dt, # - 100 &, {{"joe", "ann"}, {"C3", "C4"}}] // Dataset
```

[image]

```
MapAtKeys[dt, Style[#, Red] &, {All, {"C3", "C4"}}] // Dataset
```

[image]

The weakest point of this solution is the handling of missing values, because I have to add function after function to the `UpSet` - definitions of `mis`.  Also,
the detour of converting the `Keys` to `Position` - indices is far from perfect.

How  would a better solution look like?

Comment: Would the [`MapAtKey`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MapAtKey/) resource function help you out here?

Comment: No, `MapAtKey` doesn't work with matrices. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mF[f_, rows_, columns_] := MapAt[
  ReplaceAll[{m_Missing :> m, x_ :> f[x]}], 
  Tuples[{rows, columns}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
mF[# - 100 &, {"joe", "ann"}, {"C3", "C4"}]@dt // Dataset
```

[image]

```
mF2[Style[#, Red] &, {"joe", "ann"}, {"C3", "C4"}]@dt // Dataset
```

[image]

```
mF[Style[#, Red] &, {All}, {"C3", "C4"}]@dt // Dataset
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution. Nice how you skip the missing values using `ReplaceAll` - Thank you